# webpack exposing wrong chunk as library

Tags: webpack

I'm designing a JavaScript library that's intended to be imported as a `<script>` tag and exposes a global, like:

```
<script src="mapboard.js"></script>
<script>
  Mapboard({...});
</script>
```

I'm using webpack for bundling and distributing. My config looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    lib: './src/main.js',
    vendor: [
      'leaflet',
      'vue',
      'vuex'
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: 'Mapboard'
  }
```

I'd like to make it so the global `Mapboard` only exposes the chunk `lib`. Right now it's exposing one of the vendor libraries for some reason (`vuex`). Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use multiple entry points for a library. All entries will expose their exports under the same name and whichever you load last, "wins". If you do want multiple libraries, you could for instance use `[name]` in `output.library` as well.

But it looks like you're trying to achieve something else, namely not to bundle the dependencies with the library. In that case you should use [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/), which requires the user of the library to have the dependencies (like Vue) installed. That's very similar to how the `peerDependencies` work for npm packages. For more information you should read the [Authoring Libraries Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/) of the official docs.

If you want to make only one library that works out of the box, you should just have it all in one bundle/entry.